# WordPress - Get Posts by Last Date Update

Tags: php, wordpress

> I am trying to figure out how to construct a WordPress query that is
> going to get posts by date.
>
> What I mean by this, is that I'd like a way to output my WordPress
> posts something like this:

```
<div class="day-posts">
 <div class="day">
      <div class="title">Monday 1st January 2014</div>
      <div class="posts">
           <div class="post">
                <div class="title">Post for this day</div>
                <div class="content">Lorum ipsum dolar sit amet</div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="day">
      <div class="title">Tuesday 2nd January 2014</div>
      <div class="posts">
           <div class="post">
                <div class="title">Post for this day</div>
                <div class="content">Lorum ipsum dolar sit amet</div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set order of it by its `publish_date`.
If you change the order to DESC you will get the posts in **Descending order** from the date it was published.

`'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'publish_date', 'order' => 'DESC'`

If you change the order to ASC you will get the posts in **Ascending order** from the date it was published.

`'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'publish_date', 'order' => 'ASC'`

For updated posts in `DESC` order,

`'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'modified', 'order' => 'DESC'`

Comment: "thanks" "+1" thanks, but I want to list the posts, not by the date of publication, but by the date of update of the post, list the posts that have been modified.

Comment: I have updated the answer for updated posts as well. Enjoy!